# Mask utilizando flask não carrega

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, mask

Este é o cabeçalho:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-2.1.4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.js') }}"></script></script>
```

Este é o código do campo que quero colocar a máscara de CPF (000.000.000-00):

```
         <div class="col-sm-4">
            <strong>{{ perfilForm.CPF.label }}</strong>  
            {{ perfilForm.CPF(class_="form-control", value=meuPerfil.CPF) }}
          </div>
```

Dentro do main.js tenho esta estrutura:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#CPF').mask('000.000.000-00');
} );
```

No entanto não entra no momento que eu digito os números. Alguém pode me dar a dica?

Comment: Olá Filipe! Deu uma olhada no console para ver se mostra algum erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando o [jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) que não é parte integrante do jQuery e, portanto, precisa ser carregado também. Aliás, aquele "_=" está correto? Este exemplo usando HTML puro funcionou:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id='cpf'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mask.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#cpf').mask('000.000.000-00');
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sim, o `class_=` é como você define classes personalizadas em wtforms

Comment: Adicionado o jQuery antes do jQuery Mask e funcionou! Valeu!